# Save Bitmap of Full Size Image After Scaling

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, surfaceview

My application uses a `SurfaceView` to show an image to the user, and have them manipulate stickers on top of the image that has been taken. To reduce memory usage, I have scaled all of these bitmaps to fit within the screen. Now I want to save the image that the user just put all of the stickers on, and I would like to save it with the resolution of the original image. How would a go about doing this without loading the full-size images into memory and risking an `OutOfMemoryError`? I do not know where to start with this, it seems like an impossible task with the given tools.

Comment: Not impossible - just a bit tricky ;-)

Comment: add `android:largeHeap=true` in your application tag inside Manifest!

Comment: @Muhammad Babar I hear setting `android:largeHeap=true` is not best practice. I think I am going to try to reduce my memory usage as much as possible, and use that as a last resort.

Comment: Bryan in your case its suitable. Because you want to load the whole bitmap in memory without down sizing it!

Comment: @Muhammad Babar Thank you, I ended up using `android:largeHeap=true`, no matter how much I tried to lower my memory usage (even by shrinking the image), I was still getting `OutOfMemortyError` on some devices. So in the end, with large heap on I managed to keep the full size image, and reuse most of the sticker bitmaps to keep the memory usage as low as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you want to save the bitmap without downsizing it. There are two options.

1. Use largeHeap=true in your Application tag (Manifest).
2. If you can afford a bit of loss in quality! Compress the bitmap using.

**Sample Code**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Below is the link to the documentation of compress method of Bitmap class.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: I ended up having to use `largeHeap=true`, it was just using too much memory on some devices. It was mostly a culmination of a bunch of methods to keep memory down, but in the end I still needed to use a large heap. I actually still have some issues on select devices (notably the Samsung Galaxy S4 and S5), that do not like to load a full-size image from their own camera in portrait mode. Oddly enough, landscape works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following: You have to decouple the editing and the composition. In editing you save what the user wants in some POJOs ( e.g. sticker number A at position X,Y with rotation R ) 
Then in the composition-step you work with the Hi-Res images - but only one by one to save memory. 
In the worst case you have to work with tiles if you still hit memory constraints.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Originally I was not scaling my images at all, and it was working fine on my Nexus tablet and emulators (until about 16 stickers or so, depending on the size of the original image, but I could work with that). But it would throw an `OutOfMemoryError` on some devices as soon as I would load an image taken from the camera (Samsung devices in particular). So if I have to load the original image into memory at all, I think it will have to be a much smaller image on some devices.

Comment: Don't be afraid - fear is not helping to solve the problem. Take it as an interesting challenge and be proud once you did it ;-)